# Jsp session value

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, session, servlets

I have the following question, and want to check if i got it right or not.

```
<title>Exam</title>
</head>
<body>
<% Integer times = (Integer)(session.getAttribute("times")) ;
if (times == null) { times = new Integer(0) ; }
else { times = new Integer(times.intValue() + 1) ;
session.setAttribute("times", times) ;}
%>
times = <%=times %>
```

User A makes the first access to Exam. The page he receives back says times=0. Complete the times=*_* below, assuming the following events happen in exactly the sequence described.

1. User A makes his second access to Exam from the same browser window. He receives back
   times=*_*_.
2. User B makes his first access to Exam from another computer. He receives back times=*_*_.
3. User A makes his third access to Exam from yet another computer. He receives back
   times=*_*_.

   1. 1
   2. null
   3. null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you close your else block

```
<title>Exam</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <% Integer times = (Integer)(session.getAttribute("times")) ;
    if (times == null) { times = new Integer(0) ; }
    else { times = new Integer(times.intValue() + 1) ;}
    session.setAttribute("times", times) ;
 %>
 times = <%=times %>
```

1. 1
2. 0
3. 0

Your answer above is wrong, times will never be null. What code is doing is storing a integer in session and incrementing it each time you access it in same session.

`In same session` means from same computer, from same browser, without deleting cookie(Jsessionid). Jsessionid cookie is created by web container to track sessions.

Comment: what you mean by close the else block,    i think the question is asking  "receives back times" which is session.getAttribute("times") should that "null" when then second user enter from other computer?

Comment: above code will result in compilation error as your else block is not closed using }

Comment: fixed, but can you answer my second question?

Comment: actually you should close it as I shown. If you are closing like what you did now, then you will get 0, for all users irrespective of no if times as we are not storing anything in session.

Comment: so, if i close like what you did, so userB access this page from another computer , when the code"Integer times = (Integer)(session.getAttribute("times")) ; " time =0? , same for the UserA from another computer

Comment: Integer times = (Integer)(session.getAttribute("times")) ; // times==null

Comment: after that we are checking for null and setting it as zero, so on printing out it always prints 0.